# Gson class not found

Tags: java, gradle, gson

I have **gradle.build** file where I get **Gson** library. So, the **question** is: does gradle download gson.jar or I need to do it manually?

Here is my **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

But after executing following code it **fails**, because it can't find **Gson**:

```
private static class StoreHandler implements HttpHandler {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
            String data = "hi!";
            httpExchange.getResponseBody().write(gson.toJson(data).getBytes());
        }
    }
```

Stacktrace is following(ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson):

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7533 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/nazariy/idea/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/nazariy/Desktop/g/preproduction_practice/store/build/classes/java/main:/home/nazariy/idea/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain com.epam.moshenskyi.server.MainServer
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
    at com.epam.moshenskyi.server.http.HttpServerImpl$StoreHandler.<init>(HttpServerImpl.java:31)
    at com.epam.moshenskyi.server.http.HttpServerImpl$StoreHandler.<init>(HttpServerImpl.java:30)
    at com.epam.moshenskyi.server.http.HttpServerImpl.run(HttpServerImpl.java:22)
    at com.epam.moshenskyi.server.MainServer.main(MainServer.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
```

**UPDATE:**
If I recreate project add add Gson dependency from very beginning, everything is OK and Gson works, but if I add new dependency to existing project it throws ClassNotFound. Probably it can't recreate jar file with my project and put Gson in there?

Comment: Are you building your project with `gradle build`?

Comment: Yes. I run this command in terminal.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the file has `import com.google.gson.Gson;` ?

Comment: Yes.  I did it..

Comment: @NazariyMoshenskiy is the problem solved for you?. I am facing this same issue with Gson (ClassNotFoundException), Please let me know if something worked for you.

Comment: Try to refresh all Gradle projects as shown in second step of Neeraj  Jain’s answer. Worked for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just tried importing `gson` dependency in my `gradle` file and it ran perfectly. You can try these 2 things.

1) Make sure you have this `import com.google.gson.Gson;` statement( which you said you have in the comment section).

2) Try Clicking `Refresh all Gradle projects` as shown in the image. (this is required if when creating a new Gradle project you didn't check `import automatically option`.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I did all the steps above. my problem appears when I try to add gradle to existing project(in which were no gradle) and after adding it doesn't find any dependency listed in build.gradle. but if I add gradle while creating new project everything works. so, the problem is with adding gradle after creating project

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the environment in which you're working just adding a dependency to `build.gradle` might(not) be handled automatically by IDE. Please try to run `gradle build` from commandline - it should work there, assuming that you imports are fine in the source.

After your edit with provided output from the console it's clear now - your classpath doesn't include dependencies downloaded by gradle. You need to add them to classpath.

Comment: OP already responded in question comment before you posted this that they ran gradle build in terminal